ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC, database-first, C#: trying to add identity with migration
I have a DbContext named context1 to which I added a dependency of IdentityDbContext. I also added the necessary NuGet package for entity Identity in the data access layer project.
After scaffolding and adding Identity to the scaffold in the project where my views are, I encounter a persistent error when trying to create a migration. The error prompts me to define which database context I am using, even when I change the DbContext name to context2 in the newly created views project.
I've confirmed that the database connection is functioning properly. However, despite watching several videos, reading through other problems and answers and following steps similar to those for .NET 6, I've reached a dead end. Does anyone have any suggestions for what I can do in this situation? Thanks in advance.

Can you provide copy of the DbContext code. Without having it to review it is difficult to troubleshoot.


I've confirmed that the database connection is functioning properly.
However, despite watching several videos, reading through other
problems and answers and following steps similar to those for .NET 6.

According to your scenario, inheriting context1 from IdentityDbContext might cause conflicts because you already have existing tables managed by context1.
So you could follow couple of steps in order to successfully migrate your project.
First of all, you could separate DbContext for Identity. This way would keep your existing database schema separate from Identity's tables, avoiding conflicts.
In this scenario, you need to have two Dbcontext within your program.cs file. As following:
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

builder.Services.AddDbContext<IdentityDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

Alternatively, you could first scaffold Identity configuration because you would also need to migrate from .NET 6 to .NET 8. So once you have successfully implemented Identity within your .NET 8 project, then you could also create the class based on your previous database schema which written on .NET6, this way, initially you would need some additional hassle but in long run you would get lot of benefits, also you would finally move to code first, because Identity has written in code first approach.
Furthermore, I would say, it would completely depends on your preference though but mixing two approach always introduced some additional hassle. So try to sick with one approach even you might need to take some hassle initially, but trust me it would make your life and application more structured and maintainable.
Note: Please refer to this official document for more details or working sample.
